# How to access private s3 objects from its URL, if my app has Cognito authentication system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

My app is totally dependent upon Amplify. I can upload file to S3 using Amplify but my problem is amplify download is very much slower than normal httpRequests. If you have little bit knowledge about android then there are too many libraries which can fetch media very fast. So I decided to read the s3 objects from its URL. First I thought I should make my s3 bucket completely public but AWS recommend not to make bucket completely public. I agree.

**But now my question is my app has signin system & how to access the private s3 object from its URL after signin to my?**

**EDIT-1**

[image: Presigned URLs use]

Comment: How are you uploading to S3? Is there any backend API for that or you are using Web Identity Federation to get temporary credentials on client?

Comment: @AnkushJain ```   Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
            "ExampleKey",
            exampleFile,
            result -> Log.i("MyAmplifyApp", "Successfully uploaded: " + result.getKey()),
            storageFailure -> Log.e("MyAmplifyApp", "Upload failed", storageFailure)
    );``` before using this you have to add authentication in your app

Comment: Did you try Amplify.Storage.getUrl? 
 https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/android/#generate-a-download-url

Comment: @AnkushJain I got it. Amplify.Storage.getUr is returning a URL with a security token to access objects but my question is, is there any expiry date of that token?

Comment: @AnkushJain they recommend use a pre-signed URL for download purposes only.